# Equivalent R function h2o.transform in Python

Tags: python, transform, h2o

In Python (H2O version 3.20.0.9) which function is equivalent to `h2o.transform` in R?

```
h2o.transform(modelo_w2v, words_h, aggregate_method = 'AVERAGE')
```

Comment: isn't the `h2o.transform` ? (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html)

Comment: as.h2o could be an answer. https://dzone.com/articles/exploring-amp-transforming-h2o-data-frame-in-r-and

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html?highlight=aggregate_method#transforming-words-to-vectors), it is the same in Python as well as R:

> A transform function is available for use with Word2vec. This function
>   transforms words to vectors using an existing Word2Vec model and has
>   the following usage **(in both R and Python)**

Code from the documentation:

```
h2o.transform(word2vec, words, aggregate_method)
```

Answer (score 0):

**As stated in my comment, it's the same:**

```
 h2o.transform(word2vec, words, aggregate_method)
```

**Documentation:** http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html

**Source code:** https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/h2o/model/word_embedding.py#L28

---

[image]